# Creating an GtkGLExt drawing area after the top level window has been shown

Tags: opengl, haskell, gtk

I've been trying to solve the following problem: I need to create a drawing area using OpenGL in a Haskell application *while the application is running*. In the actual application, the drawing area will reside in a notebook tab (and there can be more than one).

It's straight-forward to get a drawing area running that is initialized before the top-level window is shown. However, when I try to fit the area into the window *after* it has been shown and realized, I'm not able to actually draw into the drawing area anymore. All I get is a large area filled with background color.

I've been able to reduce the problem to a rather minimal example, which I've uploaded [here](http://lpaste.net/107118). Here, the drawing area is created upon clicking the button. There should be a white box drawn inside, which isn't there.

How can I fix this and what is causing this problem?